# Проблема с установкой расширений в VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Раньше все хорошо работало, но в один момент вылетел VS Code и все расширения упали и не скачиваются, при попытке переустановить редактор ничего не помогает, вот какой лог я ловлю при попытке установки одного из расширений ( Python )

```
 Cannot read the extension from /Users/denisharitonciksergeevic/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.14.0: Error: Cannot read the extension from /Users/denisharitonciksergeevic/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.14.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна из возможных причин проблемы может быть связана с поврежденным или неправильно установленным расширением Python. Попробуй сделать так:

1. Открой папку расширений в проводнике твоего операционной системы. В твоем случае, это /Users/denisharitonciksergeevic/.vscode/extensions/.
2. Удалите папку ms-python.python-2023.14.0, которая соответствует расширению Python.
3. Запусти VS Code снова и попробуй установить расширение Python. Попробуй выполнить команду "Показать и установить предлагаемые расширения" (Show and Install Recommended Extensions) из панели активности или перейдите в меню "View" -> "Extensions" (Вид -> Расширения) и найдите "Python" в списке.

Если это не решит проблему, попробуй выполнить следующие действия:

1. Удали полностью VS Code с твоей системы, включая папку с настройками (обычно это ~/.vscode или ~/Library/Application Support/Code).
2. Перезагрузите компьютер.
3. После перезагрузки скачай и установи последнюю версию VS Code с официального сайта.
4. Открой VS Code и попробуй установить расширение Python снова.

Comment: окей, возможно, это и есть решение, но у меня отсутствует папка .vscode

Comment: @ДенисХаритончик ты в этом уверен?

Comment: просто такого не может быть